# T-SQL script to search for string in database and show table name and record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a script that will search a database for a string and list the table name and column. I need to get it to list not just the column but the whole record so I can compare accounts in text. How would I change the script to show the entire record and not just the column?

```
USE powercampustest
DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100) = '93335' --Five,Test
DECLARE @Results TABLE (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL

BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE         TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)

    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE         TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND    TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')
                AND    QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL

        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
            )
        END
    END    
END

SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM @Results

    /*
    ColumnName  ColumnValue
    [dbo].[ADDRESS].[PEOPLE_ORG_CODE_ID]    P000092436
    [dbo].[ADDRESS].[PEOPLE_ORG_ID] 000092436
    [dbo].[ADDRESSHIERARCHYUNIQUE].[PEOPLE_ORG_CODE_ID] P000092436
    [dbo].[ADDRESSSCHEDULE].[PEOPLE_ORG_CODE_ID]    P000092436
    [dbo].[ADDRESSSCHEDULE].[PEOPLE_ORG_CODE_ID]    P000092436
    [dbo].[ADDRESSSCHEDULE].[PEOPLE_ORG_CODE_ID]    P000092436
    [dbo].[ADDRESSSCHEDULE].[PEOPLE_ORG_CODE_ID]    P000092436
    [dbo].[ADDRESSSCHEDULE].[PEOPLE_ORG_ID] 000092436
    [dbo].[ADDRESSSCHEDULE].[PEOPLE_ORG_ID] 000092436
    [dbo].[ADDRESSSCHEDULE].[PEOPLE_ORG_ID] 000092436
```

Comment: Thanks I still get a similar result, with the column value, I'm trying to get the value of the record with all of the columns.

ColumnName ColumnValue
[dbo].[PEOPLE].[PEOPLE_CODE_ID] P000088295
[dbo].[PEOPLE].[PEOPLE_ID] 88295
[dbo].[PEOPLE].[PEOPLE_ID] 88295
[dbo].[PEOPLE].[PEOPLE_ID] 88295
[dbo].[PEOPLE].[PEOPLE_ID] 88295
[dbo].[PEOPLE].[PEOPLE_ID] 88295

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the script you currently have is, well, kind of bad.
Loops are almost never the correct approach in SQL, nested loops are even worst.

Second, since you are searching all the tables in the database, your best option to get the entire row content is as XML. This will enable you to have a single table with only 3 columns to keep all the information you need: `ColumnName`, `ColumnValue`, and `RowContent`.
It will also enable you to go with a set based approach and loose the loops.

So first, you declare the search parameter and the variable that will hold your query:

```
DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100) = 'P000092436',
        @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''
```

Then, you use the built in views of `Information_schema.Columns` and `Information_schema.Tables` to create your query:

```
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 
'UNION 
SELECT '''+ QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_SCHEMA) +'.'+ QUOTENAME(c.TABLE_NAME) +'.'+ QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME) +''' As ColumnName, -- This gets you the full column name
'''+ @SearchStr +''' As ColumnValue,
(SELECT * FROM '+ QUOTENAME(c.TABLE_NAME) +' WHERE '+ QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME) +' LIKE ''%'+ @SearchStr +'%'' FOR XML AUTO) -- This gets you the row content
FROM '+ QUOTENAME(c.TABLE_NAME) +' 
WHERE '+ QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME) +' LIKE ''%'+ @SearchStr +'%''
'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t ON c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
WHERE t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Then, use `STUFF` to remove the first `UNION`:

```
SET @SQL = STUFF(@SQL, 1, 7, '')
```

No, the query this will create is something like this:

```
SELECT '[schema].[table1].[column1]' As ColumnName, 
'P000092436' As ColumnValue,
(SELECT * FROM [table1] WHERE [column1] LIKE '%P000092436%' FOR XML AUTO)
FROM [table1] 
WHERE [column1] LIKE '%P000092436%'
UNION 
SELECT '[schema].[table1].[column2]' As ColumnName, 
'P000092436' As ColumnValue,
(SELECT * FROM [table1] WHERE [column2] LIKE '%P000092436%' FOR XML AUTO)
FROM [table1] 
WHERE [column2] LIKE '%P000092436%'
UNION....
```

Including all tables and all columns.

The next step is to create the temporary table to hold the results:

```
CREATE TABLE #SearchResults
(
    ColumnName nvarchar(500), 
    ColumnValue nvarchar(100), 
    RowContent xml
)
```

and insert the result of this query into it:

```
INSERT INTO #SearchResults
EXEC(@SQL)
```

[You can see a live demo on Rextester.](http://rextester.com/IKDJIM79839)

Comment: Thanks, that is a great solution. It makes for a very long string with the column headings included. Since I want to compare the text data in diffuse I might comment out the column name so I just get the data

Comment: I  got this error Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Argument data type xml is invalid for argument 1 of like function.
Msg 6831, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
FOR XML AUTO requires primary keys to create references for 'FileContent'. Select primary keys, or use BINARY BASE64 to obtain binary data in encoded form if no primary keys exist.

Comment: I've never seen this error before. Is it from my code?

Comment: yes, i just copy and past the code, it worked great on my desktop with sql server 2008r express, but on the server 2008r enterprise i got this error. it has very little ram, maybe it just ran out of memory